# ItemFileWriteStore vs dojo.store.Memory?

Tags: spring-mvc, datagrid, dojo

I'm using dojo 1.6 and I wanna create a store to connect to a grid; however, in dojo 1.6 only exists two ways with ItemFileWriteStore and  store Memory which of these two is  the best ?

I'm working with spring 2.5 for the controller.

Comment: Dojo 1.6 has Memory store? I don't think so. :) Interesting question though. I've never managed to start up a grid, using Memory store(in 1.9.1).

Comment: According to the reference guide it's there from 1.6.

Comment: Yes, dojo/store was originally added in Dojo 1.6, so it has dojo/store/Memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not necessarily a "right" answer to this but here are some things to consider.

The `dojo/store` API is intended to be the next step forward, replacing `dojo/data`.  Therefore, `dojo/store` is recommended from a best/modern practices point of view.

However, assuming you're talking about `dojox/grid`, that component only knows how to consume `dojo/data` stores.  That leaves you with two options:

- Use `dojo/data/ItemFileWriteStore`
- Use `dojo/store/Memory` wrapped in `dojo/data/ObjectStore` (which wraps a `dojo/store` with `dojo/data` APIs so that consumers of old stores can work with it)

Another thing worth considering is that `dojo/store/Memory` doesn't support directly pulling data in from a URL, while `dojo/data/ItemFileWriteStore` does.  If you're intending to load your data from another URL, you can still use `dojo/store/Memory`, but you'd have to XHR the data yourself first.

Comment: Thanks  primarily a put the arguments of the xhr  var xhrArgsSolEnv = {
           url : "BandejaDrawback.htm?action=conSolPrelim",
           handleAs : "json"
         };

Answer (score 0):

Thanks  primarily a put the arguments of the xhr

`var xhrArgsSolEnv = {
           url : "BandejaDrawback.htm?action=conSolPrelim",
           handleAs : "json"
         };`

then i invoke the function

`var cargarSolicEnv = dojo.xhrGet(xhrArgsSolEnv);`

`var xhrArgsSolEnv = {
           url : "BandejaDrawback.htm?action=conSolPrelim",
           handleAs : "json"
         };`

and populate the grid

`function js_solicitudEnv(data){`

```
            var mydata = new dojo.store.Memory({data : data});
    var store = new dojo.data.ObjectStore({objectStore: mydata});

    var layoutSolEnv = [{ name : "Orden", field : "orden",width : "10%",styles: "text-align: center;" },
                        { name : "Solicitud", field : "numSolicitud",width :"15%" , styles: "text-align: center;" 
                          ,formatter: function(value){return "<a href='#'>"+value+"</a>";}},
                        { name : "Fecha de Registro" ,field: "fecRegistro", width :"25%",styles: "text-align: center;"},
                        { name : "Monto", field: "mtoSolicitado", width :"20%",styles: "text-align: center;"},
                        { name : "Estado", field: "estado", width :"30%",styles: "text-align: center;"}];


    var gridSolicEnv = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
        store :  store,
        structure : layoutSolEnv,
        style : "width : 800px; height : 150px"
    },"gridSolicEnv");

    gridSolicEnv.startup();


    var btnNuevaSol =  new dijit.form.Button({
        showlabel : true,
        label : "Nueva Solicitud",
        onClick : function(){ 
                    window.location.href = "BandejaDrawback.htm?action=valAccRegistrodeSolicitud";
                  }
    },"btnNuevaSol"); 

    if(data.totalCount >=5){
      btnNuevaSol.set("disabled",true);
    }
}
```